# gcc vs. visual studio macro expansion

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, gcc, c-preprocessor

given the following code:

```
void doSomething(int one, int two, int three)
{
   //something here
}

#define ONE 1,2,3

#define TWO(arg) doSomething(arg);

#define THREE(arg) TWO(arg)

void doSomethingElse()
{
   TWO(ONE)

   THREE(ONE)
}
```

visual studio 2010 has the following preprocessor output (omitting some blank lines):

```
void doSomething(int one, int two, int three)
{

}    

void doSomethingElse()
{
   doSomething(1,2,3);

   doSomething(1,2,3);    
}
```

while gcc 4.2 gives the following:

```
void doSomething(int one, int two, int three)
{

}    

void doSomethingElse()
{
   doSomething(1,2,3);

myFile.cpp:17:13: error: macro "TWO" passed 3 arguments, but takes just 1 
   TWO
}
```

I'm not sure which is standard, but I'd like it to work like visual studio is working. Is there a way to refactor the code so that it works this way in both compilers?

Comment: Usually when VS and gcc differ, it's gcc that's correct.

Comment: This is a known bug in the Visual C++ preprocessor:  it does not expand macros prior to rescanning.  gcc's behavior is correct.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses...in terms of the solutions presented, I think I simplified my example too much and couldn't get them to work. I found another workaround but it's not illustrative to this general issue so I'll omit it here.

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility would be parenthesizing the argument so that it doesn't become 3 arguments in the substitution:

```
#define ONE 1,2,3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
#define TWO_PARENS(arg) doSomething arg;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
#define TWO(arg) TWO_PARENS((arg));                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
#define THREE(arg) TWO_PARENS((arg))
THREE(ONE)
```

BTW gcc is right according to the spec.

Answer (score 2):

Commas need special handling when you're using them within another macro.

This should work:

```
#define ONE() 1,2,3
#define TWO(ARG) doSomething(ARG());
#define THR(ARG) TWO(ARG)
```

You delay `ONE` being replaced immediately by turning it into function like macro itself.

You can see more examples of avoiding this with `BOOST_PP_COMMA_IF` on the [boost documentation site](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/comma_if.html).